# How to increase space between text label and detail text label in table view cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

How to increase space between text label and detail text label in table view cell?

I want to do this programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***My updated answer)***

I suspect you are using a standard UITableViewCell.

You should create your own subclassed UITableViewCell and put the labels on them directly with as much space as you want between them.

***My original answer)***

If you're doing this programatically (you're not clear if you're doing this as an Objective-C/Cocoa app), you can adjust row height via:

UITableViewDelegate's [tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3aheightForRowAtIndexPath%3a) method

or

UITableView's [`rowheight`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/rowHeight) property

In Interface Builder (built into XCode 4.2 instead of being a separate app), you can also adjust the row height property in the Size inspector.

Comment: I want to do this programmatically. I know how to adjust height of row. I want to adjust space between lines.

Comment: Your question still is not very clear. Do you want space between each line separating the table view cells? or a thicker line between each table view cell?

Comment: and I've offered a new suggestion in my official answer.  You'll need to create and layout your own subclassed UITableViewCell (with the space you want between your labels).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand, you want to increase the space between two cells and want to increase the width of separator line which is between the cells.

If you are looking for something readymade in form of some method or delegate, it is not available... you have to write your own trick for this one...!!

Best of luck...! 
Sam

Comment: No. I want to increase the space between lines in one cell.

Comment: space between lines in one cell? U mean you are putting some text in cell.textlabel.text and you want the spacing in multiline text to be more in height?

Comment: I want to increase space between text label and detail text label in table view cell.